# Automate SSH connection over proxy server

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am trying to write a very simple bash script, so I can first ssh to a proxy server, then from the proxy server, ssh to a destination server. This is how the network was set up to be accessed. I have:

```
#! /bin/bash
ssh  proxyservername
ssh  destservername
```

Which does not work. When I am connected to proxyserver, the second line of ssh is not executed, I still need to manually type in the command. Is there some commands I can add to the script, so I can be connected to destination server automatically? (I'm ok with being prompted for password.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most common solution in similar situations is to use the `-R` flag of `ssh` (check `man ssh`). You might also want to read about `-f` and `-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes`.

The pattern I use is something like this:

```
ssh -f -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R localhost:2222:$TARGETNAME:22 $PROXYNAME sleep 1 &&
ssh -p 2222 localhost
```

(where `2222` is basically any port you can use on the local machine).

The `-R` flag tells `ssh` to connect to `$PROXYNAME`, set up a tunnel from there to port `22` of `$TARGETNAME` and attach its other end to port `2222` on you local machine. Other options tell `ssh` to go to background and close this connection when it is no longer used. Then you just start another `ssh` instance that connects to port `2222` on `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something along the lines of `ssh proxyservername 'ssh  destservername'` assuming that `proxyservername` has ssh installed an access to destservername.